# Google Maps API: how to tell if a marker is hidden by another marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that has markers programmatically placed on it based on values in my database. When you click on a marker, it will go to a detail page for that location.

My problem is that when the map is sufficiently zoomed out, markers that are close enough to each other appear as a single marker, in effect hiding some of the markers. **Is there a way to tell programmatically whether a marker is part of a group of markers or is hidden/covered up by other markers?**

My intention is to do something like this for each dynamically generated marker:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    // if marker is not hiding any other markers
    window.location.href = markerURL;
    // else if it is hiding markers/is part of a group of markers
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

I have checked the [Marker API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker), but can't seem to find any useful methods. `getClickable` and `getVisible` always return `true` in my case, regardless of whether a marker is covered by another marker. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: You might want to use the [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) to make it obvious when multiple markers are clustered.

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you for the suggestion. I considered this, but was hoping there was an easier way. I don't need to have any control over the clustering, I just want to know whether it has happened or not. I might end up using that library after all through, if I can't find a better solution.

Comment: There is nothing built in to the API to do anything like this and I suspect any algorithm you come up with won't be as simple or as intuitive as the marker clusterer

Comment: @geocodezip I see. I am very new to the API, and while I find the Google Maps API's instructional/howto documentation to be some of the best out there, I sometimes have trouble finding what I need in the documentation for the classes themselves (probably this is my failing). I was hoping this was a case where I had just failed to find an `isClustered` property or something similar. Looks like I will be diving into MarkerClusterer. Thanks again!

Comment: The markers aren't clustered (unless you use a clusterer), the ones in the back just can't be seen or clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) to solve my problem. I was hoping for a simpler solution, but this turned out to be pretty simple after all.

The only thing I needed to add to my existing marker-generating code was a list: `var markers = [];`, and then I called `markers.push(marker);` on all of my markers. The final step was to create a new `MarkerClusterer` object:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, options);
```

And MarkerClusterer handles the rest more or less (the `options` parameter is optional, but I used it to set the path to my images and set the maximum zoom level). Now, in the situations where previously my markers were stacked on top of each other, making it impossible to see or click certain markers at certain zoom levels, I instead see a cluster with a number indicating the number of markers in that cluster. Clicking the cluster icon will further zoom in, revealing my markers.

All of this was done following the [simple usage example](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer#usage) on their github page, but they have [pretty good documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html) too. Most of my time getting this to work right was actually spent styling the cluster icons to match my site's color scheme...

[image]